# position DIV left, middle, right

Tags: html

I have 3 `div` which I want to position on the left, middle, and right side of the page respectively such that it looks like:

[left panel]       [mid panel]        [right panel]

I tried this:

```
<div id="left panel" style="display: inline-block; float: left;"></div>

<div id="mid panel" style="display: inline-block; margin:auto ; float:none;"></div>

<div id="right panel" style="display: inline-block; float:right; "></div>
```

but the `mid panel` does not align to the **middle of the page**.

edit:

My intention of aligning the 3 panels left, middle, and right of the page is so that the panels will occupy the entire web page regardless of the web browser's dimension.

i.e. I want to align `mid panel` to the middle of the page, not to the middle of the other 2 `div`.

Comment: Float the three panels to the left. Probably you need to set the width of each div in percentage to add up to 100%.

Comment: and remove `display: inline-block` from each of the div.

Comment: and just another note. your `id` has a wrong values. id field cannot have two letters. they look like more of a `class` than an `id`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting float to left for all the divs?

Comment: and remove `display: inline-block;` from each of the div?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i want to align to the middle of the page, not to the middle of the other 2 div.

Comment: You could set the divs to an percentage. For example left 34%, middle 32% and right 34%.
@X.L.Ant, As you said yourself, I can't comment because I don't have the rep.

Comment: @ArnoDeclercq My comment was generated by the review tool. Missed the reputation limitation here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @X.L.Ant correct but this doesn't mean that he should use the answer space to ask for clarifications. My opinion is this should be deleted because it is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `display: inline-block;` on middle `<div />`

Comment: this is solution for this specific code. next time when he wants to align another 3 divs then he will post another question. thus, provide him the general practice for aligning divs so he can align any number of divs, any time.

Answer (score 0):

consider this html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left panel">left</div>
    <div class="mid panel">middle</div>
    <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5TDN/

When floating elements, you'll probably want to set their width property (either with 'px' or '%'), and don't forget to put the ":after..." on their container so that it will get the full height of the highest one of the three columns inside it. This trick is also known as "clearfix"...